# Hive INSERT OVERWRITE doesnt work with ACID property enabled

Tags: hive

My basic requirement is to update a table using JOIN with another table. As that is not supported, Im trying INSERT OVERWRITE statement. But below is the error it throws

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10295]: INSERT OVERWRITE not allowed on table with OutputFormat that implements AcidOutputFormat while transaction manager that supports ACID is in use
```

I have enabled ACID properties. My query is similar to below

```
    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tbl1 SELECT 
    col1,col2,col3 ,
case when B.COL4 is not null then B.COL4 else A.COL4 end as COL4...
    FROM 
    tbl1 A 
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4..coln
      FROM tbl1 rcs LEFT JOIN TBL2... many other conditions and joins,
    ) B
    ON JOIN CONDITIONS;
```

tbl1 schema

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(
col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10),col3 varchar(10))
CLUSTERED BY (col1) INTO 2 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');
```

Comment: If its transaction table, then you should be able to update, are you getting any error while trying to update

Comment: UPDATE works with single table not when using join right?

Comment: sorry, was not aware of that, Can you please let me know if both tables used in join are transaction tables

Comment: @Vijiy yes it is

Comment: @sjd : Can you let me know how this issue was fixed , if so ?